# Register a new preset for ck_editor in TYPO3 8

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

i want to use more than one rte configurations in my installation. I configured the default preset with a yaml file which works as expected. But now i want to use an other configuration in a bodytext field of an own content element.

What i did: 
Register the new preset in ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['myset1'] = 'EXT:..../myset1.yaml';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['myset2'] = 'EXT:..../myset2.yaml';
```

in columnsOverrides of my TCA i defined:

```
'bodytext' => [
    'label' => '...',
    'config' => [
        'enableRichtext' => true,
        'richtextConfiguration' => 'myset2'
    ]
]
```

But this does not work.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Page TSconfig** to assign presets to different content elements.

The following example will set `myset2` only to the content element of CType *text*:

```
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.types.text.preset = myset2
```

Source: [docs.typo3.org – RTE CKEditor documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-use-a-different-preset)